# AutoIt script not running

Tags: autoit

```
;Tool to archive files with specific extensions grouped by that extension and kept in same file structure
;Will also keep original files in tact
;@Author - Scott Landau
;@Created - 5/23/2010
;@Last Edited - 5/23/2010

;Includes
#include <File.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Zip.au3>

;Globals
Local $tempExts="ade|adp|app|asa|ashx|asp|bas|bat|cdx|cer|chm|class|cmd|com|cpl|crt|csh|der|exe|fxp|gadget|hlp|hta|htr|htw|ida|idc|idq|ins|isp|its|jse|ksh|lnk|mad|maf|mag|mam|maq|mar|mas|mat|mau|mav|maw|mda|mdb|mde|mdt|mdw|mdz|msc|msh|msh1|msh1xml|msh2|msh2xml|mshxml|msi|msp|mst|ops|pcd|pif|prf|prg|printer|pst|reg|rem|scf|scr|sct|shb|shs|shtm|shtml|soap|stm|url|vb|vbe|vbs|ws|wsc|wsf|wsh"
Local $arrayExts = StringSplit($tempExts, "|")

;Methods
;Get the root directory for the archive
;@Return String
Func getRoot()
    Local $root = FileSelectFolder("Select Root:", "C:\")
    Return $root
EndFunc

;Gets all the subdirectories of the given directory
;@Param String
;@Return Array
Func getAllDirs($dir)
    Local $folderList = _FileListToArray($dir, "*", 2)
    Return $folderList
EndFunc

;Gets all the files of the given directory
;@Param String
;@Return Array
Func getAllFiles($dir)
    Local $fileList = _FileListToArray($dir, "*", 1)
    Return $fileList
EndFunc

;Get the file extension
;@Param String
;@Return String
Func getExt($file)
    Local $ext
    Local $pos = StringInStr($file, ".")
    $ext = StringTrimLeft($file, $pos)
    Return $ext
EndFunc

;Is bad extension?
;@Param String
;@Return Int
Func isBad($file)
    Local $retval
    Local $ext = getExt($file)
    Local $pos = _ArraySearch($arrayExts, $ext)
    If Not ($pos == -1) Then
        $retval = 1
    Else
        $retval = 0
    EndIf
    Return $retval
EndFunc

;Get all file extensions in current directory
;@Param String
;@Return Array
Func getAllExts($dir)
    Local $added = 0
    Local $allExts[1]
    Local $files = getAllFiles($dir)
    Local $max = UBound($files)
    For $i = 0 to $max - 1
        Local $ext = getExt($files[$i])
        If ($added == 0) Then
            $allExts[0] = $ext
            $added = 1
        Else
            _ArrayAdd($allExts, $ext)
        EndIf
    Next
EndFunc

;Actual archiving algorithm
;@Param String
Func algorithm($dir)
    Local $dirs = getAllDirs($dir)
    Local $files = getAllFiles($dir)
    Local $allExts = getAllExts($dir)

    Local $numExts = UBound($arrayExts)
    Local $numFiles = UBound($files)

    For $i = 0 to $numExts - 1
        Local $pos = _ArraySearch($allExts, $arrayExts[$i])
        If Not ($pos == -1) Then
            $zip = _Zip_Create(@WorkingDir & "\" & $arrayExts[$i] & "_zip.zip")
            For $j = 0 to $numFiles - 1
                Local $fileExt = getExt($files[$j])
                If ($fileExt == $arrayExts[$i]) Then
                    _Zip_AddFile($zip, $files[$j])
                EndIf
            Next
        EndIf
    Next

    Local $numDirs = UBound($dirs)
    For $k = 0 to $numDirs - 1
        algorithm($dirs[$k])
    Next

EndFunc

;Main archiving function to be run in 'Main' comment field
;Void
Func main()

    Local $root = getRoot()

    algorithm($root)

EndFunc

;Main
main()
```

Comment: You need to provide more detail AND you should probably update your original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867689/autoit-scripts-runs-without-error-but-i-cant-see-archive-update)  instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out what's wrong, you need to either:

- Add a progressbar and update it as the application runs through each function.
- Use ConsoleWrite() to help you track what the application is doing as it runs when you are debugging in Scite.
- Log your progress/success/errors to a log file that you can examine after you have run the application.

I would recommend doing all the above.

Comment: #AutoIt3Wrapper_run_debug_mode=Y
At the top of a script will make the wrapper output each line to consolewrite.

Comment: Also, using message boxes in key places, especially for variable contents, can be useful to see if the program is performing the way you'd expect at certain steps along the way.